# Why is date() applying DST incorrectly?

Tags: php, date, timezone, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert a human-readable time of 7am into a timestamp in PHP for calculation and manipulation purposes. The timestamp gets created correctly as 25200, but the date() function strangely converts the timestamp back to 08:00 when I use London as the timezone, 08:00 (correctly) when using Berlin, but 09:00 when using Athens.

I cannot understand why it does not return 07:00 and why it should be the same as Berlin. My server is in Germany and I am in London, might that have something to do with it? Hardly, since I have the same problem on my XAMPP stack here in London on my laptop.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$time_readable = 7;
$time_stamp = $time_readable * 60 * 60;
echo $time_stamp;
echo date('H\:i',$time_stamp);
```

I even preceded my code with

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

but the problem persists.

What have I overlooked?

My PHP version on the server is 5.2.12 on the German production machine and 5.3.1 on my UK laptop XAMPP stack.

Comment: What is your goal here? How do time zones fit into what you want to be your end result?

Comment: The timestamp you are calculating is treated as the time in seconds since 00:00:00 on 1st January, 1970, not since midnight last night.

Comment: I am using this to define online calendars with variable granularity as well as variable start and end times. So when I allow the user to define a start time of "7" in the GUI and a granularity of "15" minutes, I convert these to timestamps so I can then create the calendar array accordingly.

Comment: While I have used this approach for years, I am now writing a new system to use the same database, so I cannot easily change many things. For these calculations, I don't want timezones, I thought it would just calculate from 1/1/1970 irrespective of timezones, but they do seem to affect the conversion?
I do want to generally define timezones in my code for other aspects of it, but it just baffles me that the conversion will change for Athens, but not for London...

Comment: Welcome to the world of Internet time. PHP timestamps are always seconds from midnight, 1/1/1970, UTC. Local time in London will be UTC or UTC+1 depending on year and time of year. Berlin will be UTC+1 or UTC+2. Your server will probably work in whatever time is local to it unless you change it, but timestamps are still UTC. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your comment Mike. However, if PHP timestamps are from 1/1/1970 UTC, then that does not explain why `25200` as a timestamp gets converted to `08:00` with `date('H\:i',$time_stamp);` or am I misunderstanding your comment? Also, local time in London should be UTC right now and Berlin should be UTC+1, right? And Athens UTC+2? But the conversion results from `date()` return identical results for London and Berlin, but a different one for Athens...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of [what a timestamp is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and how they work. You are also not understanding [DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) properly as it is laced with political changes to how it is applied.

However, to answer your specific question

> I cannot understand why it does not return 07:00 and why it should be the same as Berlin.

Your [timestamp represents 07:00 UTC on 1st January 1970](http://3v4l.org/qkQvf). The reason setting the timezone to 'Europe/London' changes the time to 08:00 is because the UK was running the [`British Standard Time experiment`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time#Periods_of_deviation) which kept the UK on UTC + 1 from 27 October 1968 to 31 October 1971. Therefore the local time in London at 07:00 UTC on 1st January 1970 was 08:00.

I would recomend that your timestamps should always be complete timestamps that represent the full date and time. Trying to represent times only is the road to pain.

I also recomend learning to use the [DateTime classes](http://php.net/datetime) as they will handle all of this for you transparently.

Comment: Thank you, vascowhite, this helps tremendously.


I like to think that I have a basic understanding what a timestamp is and how they work, but nevertheless I had no idea that the UK would have deviated from UTC in the middle of winter :)


And you are right of course that it is time I learn DateTime classes, my use of the timestamp for manipulating times and dates served me well in the past, but very probably is unnecessarily complicated.

Thank you for for the encouragement to learn a better way to do things and especially for finally resolving a mystery that bugged me for quite a few years.